# Flex saving canvas and dropped image

Tags: apache-flex, canvas

I have an image loaded from an url and added to canvas as child. Then I am drag and dropping another image on it which also uses the senocular transform so the image can be transformed on the canvas. I have coded in such way that the transform handles shows up only after it's dropped on canvas. The image shows up correctly. But I am trying to save the result image (that is the main image and the dropped image on top of it), I only end up with the main image that was loaded earlier. The dropped image doesn't show up.

Below is the code for handleDrop() that is fired on dragDrop event and prepares the final image. What am I doing wrong?

```
var dragInitiator:IUIComponent = dragEvent.dragInitiator;
                var dropTarget:IUIComponent = dragEvent.currentTarget as IUIComponent;

                var tool:TransformTool = new TransformTool(new ControlSetStandard());
                var items:String = dragEvent.dragSource.dataForFormat("items") as String;

                var img:Image = new Image();

                img.x=50;
                img.y=50;
                img.width=55;
                img.height=55;

                img.source=items.toString();
                var bitmap:Bitmap= Bitmap(img.content);


                var tool:TransformTool = new TransformTool(new ControlSetStandard());   
                var component:UIComponent = new UIComponent( );
                tool.target = img;

                tool.x=myCanvas.x;
                tool.y=myCanvas.y;



                addElement(component);

                myCanvas.addChild(img);
                img.z=myCanvas.z+1;
                component.addChild(tool);
                original=new BitmapData(bmd.width,bmd.height,true,0x000000FF);
                original.draw(myCanvas);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you added the image to the canvas doesn't mean it has drawn already.  Either listen for the updateComplete event on the image or do a callLater to a function that then draws the bitmap.

Comment: Tried that. I create a new function with the last two lines of codes that draws the canvas to bitmapdata and used callLater to call it from the handleDrop. But it's not working.

Comment: oh wait, the source you're setting is a URL? Yeah, that's going to take a little longer than one frame to get it, then drawn it.  Just add a 'complete' event listener to the image for when it's done loading and drawn.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I ran into a different problem though. The original image size is bigger than the canvas size and the image is scaled on the canvas, however, while saving I want to save it with the original size not the canvas size. But the image in this case gets saved with the canvas size and hence is much smaller. How to save the image with the original size in this case?